# Splitting over infinite generated abelian subgroup?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Recall that a group is CSA if all its maximal abelian subgroups are malnormal.

Question 1: Can a finitely generated CSA group splits (as graph of groups) over an infinitely generated abelian subgroups?

If so, is there an explicit example?

Question 2: what are the known classes of finitely generated groups that do not split over infinitely generated subgroup?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. What I mean to ask is that is there a finitely generated CSA group that splits over infinitely generated abelian subgroups?

Comment: In question 2 do you really mean over arbitrary infinitely generated subgroups? or only abelian ones? The simplest answer is to just say groups with Property FA, but this has nothing specific to infinitely generated subgroups.

Comment: For 1 I'd try the double HNN-extension with presentation $\langle u,v,(x_n)_{n\in\mathbf{Z}}\mid $ $ux_n^2u^{-1}=x_{n+1}^3,$ $vx_n^3v^{-1}=x_{n+1}^2,$ $[x_n,x_m]=1,$ $n,m\in\mathbf{Z}\rangle$. It's finitely generated, splits over the (infinitely generated) abelian subgroup generated by the $x_n$. It's maybe CSA but I haven't checked.

Comment: In question 2, I mean over arbitrary infinitely generated subgroup, not necessarily abelian. I was hoping that the class of groups that don't split over infinitely generated groups to be (much) bigger than the class of groups that don't split at all. Finite generation of the edge groups recently become important to me, so I want to know what is known about splitting over infinitely generated groups. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it's larger. For instance consider an (infinite locally finite)-by-(infinite cyclic) f.g. group $G$, e.g. the lamplighter. Let $N$ be the locally finite normal subgroup. Let $G$ act minimally on a tree. If $N$ has a fixed point, the $N$-action is trivial. Otherwise, the $N$-action is horocyclic, so $G$ fixes its unique fixed point at infinity, hence $G$ fixes a point. It follows that the only subgroup over which $G$ splits is $N$, which is infinitely generated.

Comment: Thanks for the HNN example. But it seems that it is not CSA since both u and v conjugate something in the i.g. abelian subgroup to something also in the i.g. abelian subgroup. I tried to do similar things, while it is convenient to use HNN construction to make the group finitely generated and splits, it does not give CSA.

Comment: lamplighter example is interesting. But it is not quite what I want. I want something that splits over f.g.subgroups but not over i.g.subgroups.

Comment: Well, take any polycyclic group mapping onto $\mathbf{Z}$. It splits over the kernel but has no infinitely generated subgroup at all.

Comment: There are other examples. For instance, an irreducible lattice in a product $G\times H$, where $G=SO(3,2)$ and $H=SO(q)(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ has $\mathbf{Q}_p$-rank 1 for some suitable choice of quadratic form on 5 variables (so that $H$ has an cocompact action on a bushy tree), splits over very few subgroups, and these subgroups are finitely generated.

Comment: Re: question 1, let $H$ be a finitely generated CSA group with an infinitely generated abelian subgroup $A$ (I don't know an example of such an $H$, but I'm fairly sure it exists), and let $G=H*\mathbb{Z}$, which is also CSA.  Then we also have $G=H*_A (A*\mathbb{Z})$, so $G$ also splits over an infinitely generated abelian subgroup.  These kind of 'folding' constructions (the second splitting is a folding of the first) tend to show that most groups that split split over an infinitely generated subgroup.

Comment: Thanks, @YCor. That's very helpful. Is there a place where I can read more about your second example.

Comment: Thanks, @HJRW. That's very helpful. For the folding construction to work, one needs to find a infinitely generated subgroup that contains the edge group of another splitting. I wonder how often can one do that. I want to get a better understanding of what "most" means.

Comment: Well, for instance, any quasiconvex subgroup of infinite index in a hyperbolic group is contained in an infinitely generated subgroup.